# How to rig a folding wallet?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, surface-deform

My main concern here is to use an armature rig to control the folding motion of a leather wallet. I want the edges to be perfectly smooth at the crease without the weird deformations that are shown in the second image.

I have tried to use lattice, surface deform but nothing seemed to work. And I can't figure the appropriate bone/weight paint setup to get to function properly.

I would really appreciate your help here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could create 3 bones, one for each side, one root that is the parent, then parent *With Empty Groups*:

[image]

Assign the vertex groups to the correct group:

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to put the *Armature* modifier above the others if you don't want bad deformations:

[image]

Result:

[image]